# IndexError: list index out of range when call load_summarize_chain using PALM2

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, palm-pre

I've been struggling to solve this error for hours with no luck. I'm trying to summarize files after splitting to chunks them using the PALM model.
my code

```
refine_chain = load_summarize_chain(
    llm,
    chain_type="refine",
    ......
)
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
    separator = "\n",
    chunk_size = 1000,
    chunk_overlap  = 0)

document_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
refine_outputs = refine_chain({"input_documents": document_chunks})
```

the error:
----> 7 refine_outputs = refine_chain({"input_documents": document_chunks})

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_core/output_parsers/base.py in parse_result(self, result, partial)
220             Structured output.
221         """
--> 222         return self.parse(result[0].text)
223
224     @abstractmethod

IndexError: list index out of range.

anyone help please?